# Using a Linksys Wireless- G Broadband Router for a Wireless Antenna/Adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

(Warning: I'm not too computer-smart). Just moved from a home where I used AT&T DSL to a home with Comcast Cable for internet. The old home had the DSL ethernet wired to my only desktop with a 2Wire router for my wireless signal for the laptops.

In the new home the signal comes from the cable via a Netgear(300) wireless router (remotely located) & works fine for my laptops. After searching with the network software, my desktop (can't be ethernet wired because of location) detects no wireless signal. Desktop is a 2 yr old HP p6311f Pavilion (Windows 7). Can't seem to detect any wireless hardware (ant/adaptr). Maybe I don't have the ability & need to buy a USB wireless antenna? Would the Pavilion come with wireless capability out of the box, maybe something inside the tower? No antenna on back.

I happen to have a Linksys Wireless router which I plugged in to the desktop (trying both internet & shared ports) & noticed signal action on the router front panel. No internet on desktop though. Can I use this as an antenna for the desktop?

Thanks & sorry if my solution is an easy one I'm just missing. Just want internet on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

First the technical answer: yes, you could use the Linksys router the way you describe. Basically, you'd want to create a second network consisting of your computer and the router, and configure the router to act as bridge between the new network and the wireless network.

But this is a bit of a hassle, especially if you're "not too computer smart". An alternative is to buy a USB Wifi adapter for your desktop computer. These can be had for as little as $10, though if there are signal issues something fancier might be in order. Be sure to test the signal using your laptop before you proceed.